# Sql Query:Not able to group data from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am not able to resolve this query.

Tables are:

```
tblStandard1students
tblStandard2students
tblStandard3students     
tblCandidateinfo
```

tblStandard1students, tblStandard2students and tblStandard3students tbl contain information about students enrolled in standard 1,2 and 3.

tblStandars1students

```
Candid  admitted
  1        Y
  2        N
  3        Y


tblCandidateinfo

Candid  gender Division
  1       M      1
  2       F      2
```

and so on...

Now I want the table like this

```
Gender  Students(Standard1)  Students(Standard2)  Students(Standard3)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Male           10                 20                      30    
 Female         10                 30                      40
```

I tried this but this does not give me error:

```
SELECT case when Gender='M' then 'Male' 
            when Gender='F' then 'Female' 
       END AS Gender,

( SELECT count(*)
 FROM tblStandard1students A
 where A.Candid=B.Candid
 ) AS Students(Standard1),

( SELECT count(*)
 FROM tblStandard2students A
    where A.Candid=B.Candid
) AS Students(Standard2),

( SELECT count(*)
 FROM tblStandard3students A
    where A.Candid=B.Candid
) AS Students(Standard3)


FROM tblCandidateinfo B
group by Gender
```

Comment: I don't see either an error message posted or `ORDER BY` used. Do you mean "GROUP" instead of "SORT"?

Comment: @pst sorry! edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bbeb4/5)

```
select 
case when Gender='M' then 'Male' 
            when Gender='F' then 'Female' 
      END AS Gender,
sum(T.std1) as [Students(Standard1)],
sum(T.std2) as [Students(Standard2)],
sum(T.std3) as [Students(Standard3)]
from
tblCandidateinfo as C

JOIN
(
select Candid, 1 as std1, 0 as std2, 0 as std3 
from tblStandars1students
union all
select Candid, 0 as std1, 1 as std2, 0 as std3 
from tblStandars2students
union all
select Candid, 0 as std1, 0 as std2, 1 as std3 
from tblStandars3students
) as T on (C.Candid=T.Candid)

GROUP BY GENDER
```

Answer (score 1):

**This Query syntax works on Oracle. Basically, I have used right outer join.**

```
select case when Gender='M' then 'Male' 
            when Gender='F' then 'Female' END AS Gender,
       count(A.candid) AS "Students(Standard1)",
       сount(A1.candid) AS "Students(Standard2)",
       сount(A2.candid) AS "Students(Standard3)" 
from tblStandard1students A,
     tblStandard2students A1,
     tblStandard3students A2,
     tblCandidateinfo B
where A.candid(+)=B.candid and A1.candid(+)=B.candid and A2.candid(+)=B.candid
group by gender
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case also you can use [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operation

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Gender='M' then 'Male' 
            WHEN Gender='F' then 'Female' 
       END AS Gender, [Students(Standard1)], [Students(Standard2)], [Students(Standard3)]
FROM (
      SELECT (SELECT gender FROM tblCandidateinfo i WHERE x.Candid = i.Candid) AS gender, List
      FROM (
            SELECT Candid, 'Students(Standard1)' AS List
            FROM dbo.tblStandard1students
            UNION ALL
            SELECT Candid, 'Students(Standard2)'
            FROM dbo.tblStandard2students
            UNION ALL
            SELECT Candid, 'Students(Standard3)'
            FROM dbo.tblStandard3students
            ) x
      ) x2
PIVOT 
 (
  COUNT(List) FOR List IN ([Students(Standard1)], [Students(Standard2)], [Students(Standard3)])
  ) p
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e0cc5/1)